# Instance and roles of ASP.net MVC 2 + SS 2008 Developer

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, security-roles, user-roles, asp.net-roles

Gonna need some advice for my work.

In my computer I have installed VS2010 and SQL Server 2008 Developer with a customized instance name named MYCOMPUTER. If I need to transfer the project work, that is created with ASP.NET MVC 2 and of course I also have create a database via VS2010:s interface, from my computer into another computer that has VS2010 with light version of SQL Server 2008 with a instance named SQLEXPRESS, will it be trouble?

I also heard that if you have created roles in the ASP.net via VS and it can be more error message or  trouble in relation with SS 2008 Developer due to database's defined roles. Is it true?

// Fullmetalboy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be no troubles with **moving databases** if you will use backups or plain sql scripts (actually this is most painless way). **As for roles** - it depends on what roles are you talking about? Roles created for default [SqlRoleProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlroleprovider.aspx)? If so all you need to do is to write appropriate connection string in your web config.

Comment: *IC... I understand about the database part but how about the instance?

*About the roles - If I explain this way...is it possible that the ASP.net MVC roles can be seperated from the roles of SS2008 Developer when webbsite is connected to a database?

Comment: Yep, this is possible. Roles will be stored in the database itself and have nothing to do with SS2008 ones. And what you need to know about the incance?